# Can Material Tree load and export JSON?

Tags: json, angular, angular-material, tree, treeview

I need to do a menu editor, and I'm wondering if a Material Tree could be helpful to load the menu config, that is in JSON format, render that config in a Material Tree, make changes in the Tree (CRUD operations, drag&Drop nodes, ... ) and save it again in a JSON.

I'm pretty sure it can use a JSON to render a tree, but I couldn't find any example of exporting that tree to a JSON.

What do you think?

Comment: Hi there. if you look at the api, there's a data object that is tied to the tree. https://material.angular.io/components/tree/api. This data object can be then stringified for JSON. However, the binding has to be two way here.

Comment: @giosoftware Can You tell us what type of json data you have and wants to load with tree ? I am interested to work on it. Thank you. If you do not mind, then we can connect each other by email `grdtechlab@gmail.com` .